# AttributeError: module 'dateutil.tz' has no attribute 'UTC' on Zappa Deploy

Tags: python-3.x, zappa, python-zappa

On trying to deploy my AWS Lambda function get this error on my Stacktrace

````
(python-dateutil 2.8.1 (/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('python-dateutil<2.7.0'), {'zappa'})
Calling deploy for stage development..
Oh no! An error occurred! :(

==============

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 2778, in handle
    sys.exit(cli.handle())
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 512, in handle
    self.dispatch_command(self.command, stage)
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 549, in dispatch_command
    self.deploy(self.vargs['zip'])
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 709, in deploy
    self.zappa.create_iam_roles()
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/core.py", line 2557, in create_iam_roles
    role, credentials_arn = self.get_credentials_arn()
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/core.py", line 2536, in get_credentials_arn
    self.credentials_arn = role.arn
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 339, in property_loader
    self.load()
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 505, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 316, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 613, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict, request_context)
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 632, in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 102, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 135, in _send_request
    request, operation_model, context)
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 167, in _get_response
    request, operation_model)
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 218, in _do_get_response
    response_dict, operation_model.output_shape)
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 242, in parse
    parsed = self._do_parse(response, shape)
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 509, in _do_parse
    parsed = self._parse_shape(shape, start)
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 302, in _parse_shape
    return handler(shape, node)
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 377, in _handle_structure
    member_shape, member_node)
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 302, in _parse_shape
    return handler(shape, node)
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 377, in _handle_structure
    member_shape, member_node)
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 302, in _parse_shape
    return handler(shape, node)
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 175, in _get_text_content
    return func(self, shape, text)
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 462, in _handle_timestamp
    return self._timestamp_parser(text)
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/utils.py", line 626, in parse_timestamp
    return _parse_timestamp_with_tzinfo(value, tzinfo)
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/utils.py", line 607, in _parse_timestamp_with_tzinfo
    return dateutil.parser.parse(value, tzinfos={'GMT': tzutc()})
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py", line 1374, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py", line 660, in parse
    ret = self._build_tzaware(ret, res, tzinfos)
  File "/Users/supratik/.local/share/virtualenvs/api_sourcer-sM-JSZy3-/Users/supratik/.pyenv/shims/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py", line 1201, in _build_tzaware
    aware = naive.replace(tzinfo=tz.UTC)
AttributeError: module 'dateutil.tz' has no attribute 'UTC'

==============```
````

Comment: Hello, were you able to figure this out? I am having the same issue. I somehow got it to work yesterday but am stuck with the issue again today. I tried the answer `pip install python-dateutil` but no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`python -m pip install --upgrade python-dateutil`

Upgrading `python-dateutil` solve the problem for me. On my machine, `2.5.3` to `2.8.1`.

Skimming the source code, I found out that `UTC` variable is added in `2.7.0`. So, I think any version `>= 2.7.0` will solve the issue.

```
#: Convenience constant providing a :class:`tzutc()` instance
#:
#: .. versionadded:: 2.7.0
UTC = tzutc()
```

Answer (score 1):

Got a similar issue while trying to copy files from AWS S3 using aws cli. Running  `pip install python-dateutil` updated the python-dateutil to 2.8.1 and it works well now.

Comment: Hi, I attempted this but am still receiving the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify the python-dateutil version and install it before the package which has a error, in your case zappa
exempla:

```
 pip install python-dateutil==2.8.1 zappa
```

my case the package which i was getting a erro was freezegun, so i ran

```
pip install python-dateutil==2.8.1 freezegun==0.3.15
```

and it worked

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue where trying to run `eb deploy` for AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

**What worked for me was:** `sudo pip3 install python-dateutil --upgrade`

(note: running this without sudo did not fix the issue)

---

For reference this was the error I was getting prior to this:

```
eb deploy projectFoo
Deploying to development environment
Deploying to AWS
Creating application version archive "app-200711_113503".
Uploading projectFoo/app-200711_113503.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
ERROR: AttributeError - module 'dateutil.tz' has no attribute 'UTC'
```